# Docusign: Dynamically Populate Fields In Document

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign to send off vendor agreements.  The agreements are all the same wording, except for vendor name and address.  Is there a way I can pass information to the envelope creation script (PHP) to dynamically populate name and address fields on a template document?

Comment: Yes you can, and this has already been answered through a previous SO question.  Even though it's related to Embedded Sending the idea is still the same, use the tabLabel property.  See this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314753/embedded-signing-rest-api-php/18319313#18319313

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can definitely populate tabs in an embedded signing view. This is all controlled through the

```
tabLabel
```

property of each tab in your request body.  For instance, if you login to the DocuSign Console and add two data fields (textTabs) to your envelope where one has the label "email" and the other has a label of "address" then the following JSON body prefills those tabs based on the value passed.

```
        "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
            {
                "tabLabel": "address",
                "value": "123 Main St. SF, CA"
            },
            {
                "tabLabel": "email",
                "value": "sample@email.com"
            }
        ]
    }
}
],
"status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: Does anyone have a more updated version of this answer with full JSON?