# Is there a way to pre fill fields in an embedded docusign document?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a document that needs to be signed but the document has couple of fields that are customized for the particular person that needs to sign, and I want it to be pre-populated in the document before he signs, this is in my case the job

Is it possible to pre populate the some fields and then generate a url and display an iframe with that document?

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. Stack Overflow is to get help with existing code, not to help design workflows or ask general how-to related questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is absolutely possible.

In general you will go through three steps:

1. GET demo.docusign.net/restapi/login_information
2. POST demo.docusign.net/restapi/:version/:accountId/envelopes
3. Get DocuSign Recipient View

In step #2 is where you will be providing an envelope definition.  My advice to you is to use templates because then you can lay out the field visually and give them labels.  In your request in step #2 you will have to provide values in the following format.  JSON is below, but it's also possible with XML.

```
 "tabs":  {
        "textTabs":  [
            {
                "tabLabel": "address",
                "value": "123 Main St. SF, CA"
            },
            {
                "tabLabel": "email",
                "value": "sample@email.com"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here is another answer to this question.
[Docusign: Dynamically Populate Fields In Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925536/docusign-dynamically-populate-fields-in-document)