# initial value for custom text tab in docusign using API

Tags: docusignapi

I need to set initial value for the custom TEXT tab. so that user ll have an option he can keep the text and reenter it.
i have seen the property "Initial value" for the TEXT tab in DOCUSIGN application. But through the API, I could not find that property.

I am using Documents, Envelope option with SOAP API.

Kindly suggest how do i achieve my requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docusign: Dynamically Populate Fields In Document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925536/docusign-dynamically-populate-fields-in-document)

Comment: Have you searched the `DocuSignApi` on Stack Overflow for this info? This has been answered many times, like here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925536/docusign-dynamically-populate-fields-in-document

Comment: Yes Ergin, I have checked Docusign API and stack overflow but its not resolved the issue. The link which you have shared, that shows only setting the value. when i did follow that, it is not allowing to user to edit the Text tab value. But for my requirement I need to set the value to TEXT tab at the same time we should also give an option to user to edit the text tab.

Comment: I hope my question is clear now.

Comment: Use the `locked` property which can be found in the [API Documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/).  I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To populate initial tab value and also make it editable:

```
"textTabs": [
    {
        "tabLabel": "name",
        "value": "foo",
        "locked": "false"
    },
    {
        "tabLabel": "email",
        "value": "bar",
        "locked": "false"
    }
]
```

Comment: we are using SOAP API, I do not find the property "locked'. But I found and I checked "CustomTabLocked" but it is not worked.                                                                              CustomTabLocked = "X" & CustomTabLocked = ''; both not worked

Comment: You should specify all this info when you first post your question.  If you're using SOAP API try adding this property also `CustomTabRequiredSpecified` = `true`

Comment: I do not find mentioned property , even i could not find the same in api documentation.      https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Sending Group/Tab.htm?Highlight=radio button

Comment: Ergin,Did u get a chance to check it..?